# Passing data from within a container application into a widget loaded from script tag

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a widget that will be embedded on different sites through a  tag. I would like to allow the host website to manipulate some properties to allow it to be very configurable. I want them to be able pass properties dynamically, read them in my widget and conditionally act upon them. Passing data through `data-attr` like so:
`<script data-attr="value"/>`
is fine, but is not dynamic, once script is loaded to change the value that script is executing with it, it would probably require removing and adding new  with a different value and reloading the page.

Second option I evaluated was extending window object, but even tho it works properly in the direction script->host site it doesn't work on the way host site->script so:
`<script>window.new_atr="test"</script>` this when trying to log the value inside of the widget yields undefined.

What are some other options to do this or am I doing something wrong when extending window object?